# Category chart with datetime y axis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am rendering a category chart with time on the y-axis. This chart will show the completed time for each ticket.

```
`` http://jsfiddle.net/6oz3075d/14/
```

However, I am unable to show the date and time in DD:MM:YY format. Also the interval is in years. I tried using dateTimeFormat,tickInterval etc. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: What units are your times in ? I don't understand what you want to see on the y-axis ? A date or a time ? I think both those tasks finished on the same date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter) and [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat)

```
 labels:{
            formatter:function(){
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d:%m:%Y', this.value);
            }
 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6oz3075d/15/

Comment: I know its possible to format the date. My time is in milli seconds. I want it in HH:MM:SS, which is possible to achieve. Both the time stamps which I have specified are only a few seconds apart. Why is the tick interval in years? Should I be calculating manually the tick interval each time? Even then I tried setting the tick interval,it throws 19# error: http://jsfiddle.net/6oz3075d/16/

Comment: Set any min value, as any date (like 4.12.2014). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6oz3075d/18/